# Unable to consume artifact deployed in a private Bit-bucket repository

Tags: maven, bitbucket-pipelines, artifact, maven-wagon-plugin, wagon

I am using [wagon-git](http://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/bitbucket.html) version 0.2.5 to deploy and consume the artifact from my private bitbucket. Following the same steps as given in the documentation http://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/bitbucket.html.

Error:

`Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx:yyy:jar:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.aaa:bbb:jar:3.0: Could not find artifact com.aaa:bbb:jar:3.0 in xxx_repo (https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/company/xxx_repo/raw/releases)`

Research:

From my research, I found many suggested the problem in repository URL so I changed to
https://bitbucket.org/company/xxx_repo/raw/releases/  from this URL I am able to access the repo but the compilation fails with an error saying zip END header not found

`Compilation failure:
[ERROR] Error reading /home/msuser1/.m2/repository/com/aaa/bbb/3.0/bbb-3.0.jar; zip END header not found`

And too many warning saying checksum validation failed.

`[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from https://bitbucket.org/company/xxx_repo/raw/artifacts/com/aaa/bbb/3.0/bbb-3.0.jar: Checksum validation failed, expected <!doctype but is 2f947caee42a20633fb9c412ew53591f64b8c4481`

Solution:

**What is the exact URL for consuming the artifact from a private bitbucket?**

**Can anyone provide complete working steps to deploy and consume artifact from private bitbucket using wagon-git?**

Answer (score 1):

We have to add username, password, and HTTP Basic Auth in Maven settings.xml to fetch and pull from bitbucket/Github private repository.

````
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>your-repo-id</id>
      <username>yourgithubusername</username>
      <password>yourgithubpassword</password>
    </server>
    <configuration>
     <httpHeaders>
       <property>
        <name>Authorization</name>
        <value>BASIC-AUTH HEADER VALUE</value>
       </property>
     </httpHeaders>
    </configuration>
  </servers>
</settings>```
````